# Check customer has new invoices

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, invoice

I am trying to find a flag to determine whether a QuickBooks Customer has new invoices. I am syncing the invoices, and next time when I try to sync I want to check whether there are any new Invoices OR updated once.

There is a `syncToken` in Customer record but it only shows the updates for the Customer object.

Is there a way to check for the updated Invoices OR New onces, other than syncing all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out after @Naveen's Answer.

Basically the `syncToken` is good to use when we deal with single record at a time. We can keep `syncToken` in our database and check it against QuickBooks next time.

But when it comes to bulk record fetching its good to use `LastUpdatedTime`.

To filter invoices what I did was query QuickBooks as below,

```
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
$invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice where MetaData.LastUpdatedTime > <date>";
```

Note: `<date>` should be in long date format. Ex: 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00. We can get this date format by `date('c', mySql date);`

Cheers..!!! Thanks again @Naveen for your tip

Answer (score 1):

The way we handled this is by storing the *last sync time*. Add the *last sync time* as a filter to the QuickBooks SDK query object. First time, ALL invoices are synced. During the next sync, the ones that have been created or modified after the *last sync time* are synced. Here's a C# code sample from a Windows service that we are using:

```
using QBXMLRP2Lib;
using Interop.QBFC13;

public void SyncTransactions(QBSessionManager sessionMgr, DateTime? fromModifiedDate)
{
    IMsgSetRequest msgset = sessionMgr.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
    IInvoiceQuery invoiceQuery = msgset.AppendInvoiceQueryRq();
    invoiceQuery.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true); // true if line items from a transaction have to included in the result set
    if (fromModifiedDate != null)
    {           
        invoiceQuery.ORInvoiceQuery.InvoiceFilter.ORDateRangeFilter.ModifiedDateRangeFilter.FromModifiedDate.SetValue(fromModifiedDate.Value, false);
        invoiceQuery.ORInvoiceQuery.InvoiceFilter.ORDateRangeFilter.ModifiedDateRangeFilter.FromModifiedDate.SetTimeZone(0, 0); // UTC, since we keep the last sync time in UTC

        IMsgSetResponse msgRes = sessionMgr.DoRequests(msgset);
        IResponseList responseList = msgRes.ResponseList;
        if (responseList.Count > 0)
        {
            // process the results here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Naveen. I dont get the code, BUT I got the logic. And It WORKS...!!! Thanks